# Creating box plot on exercise

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to create a box plot on exercise:

```
boxplot(exercise, data=exercise, main="Outlier Analysis Exercise")

Error in oldClass(stats) <- cl : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

I get those error message.  It is in `survey_fixed` file and I already attached it.  `exercise` column has the value among these three:  `none`, `some` or `freq`.

DATA SAMPLE:

### exercise

some
none
none
none
some 
freq
freq
freq

I wonder what I did wrong?  and how to fix it?

Comment: Uh, I don't think the attachment came through.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your code and try giving some sample data. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or check out the other `r`-tagged question with some upvotes to get some ideas

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you the issue: you can't use only factors to create a box plot. boxplot is looking for a numeric vector. Run code below as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
"age" = c(77,74,55,62,60,59,32,91,75,73,43,67,58,18,57),
"party" = c("Independent", "Independent", "Independent", "Democrat", 
          "Independent", "Republican", "Independent", 
          "Independent", "Democrat", "Republican", "Republican", 
          "Democrat", "Democrat", "Independent", "Independent"),
)

df$party <- as.factor(df$party)
df$age <- as.numeric(df$age)

boxplot(df$party) # gives same error
boxplot(df$age) #runs
```

see `?boxplot` for examples on using formulas in the boxplot function, as that may be what you are looking for? For example:

```
 boxplot(df$age~df$party)
```